# Issues with re-directing, need to force lowercase in url

Tags: php

i want to force lowercase GETs, i am using disqus.com commenting system, and i serve pages based on a GET, disqus.com does not differentiate

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/words/?w=Hej
```

and

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/words/?w=hej
```

it serves comments for different pages.

What would be the best way to fix this issue? I cannot seem to use .htcacess from what i have read, and i dont want to serve a 404 if its uppercase, is there any other way to force lowercase in the URL ?

EDIT 2:

I tried my own solution

```
$page = urldecode($_GET['w']);
$lowerPage = strtolower($page);

if ($page !== $lowerPage) {

     header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/words/?w=". $lowerPage);
     die();
}
```

Works fine in Firefox, Google adds a delay on the redirect though - anyway testing the solution below now.

Comment: [`strtolower()`](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way it can be done in Apache mod_rewrite.

1. First enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf.
2. Lowercasing a URL will need you to add this line in your httpd.conf and bounce Apache process:

   RewriteMap lc int:tolower
3. Then put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT directory:

Once you verify it to be working change R=302 to R=301.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^A-Z]*[A-Z].*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I dont think i have access to httpd.conf.

Comment: That's unfortunate, you can try requesting this small change from your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

when you print out your link use this

echo " http://www.mydomain.com/words/?w=".strtolower(Hej);

Comment: Clearly that would work, but it would not disable the users ability to write it in

Comment: John whatever you do in this url users always have the ability to ply with the url in the browser. if you dont want user to see the urls then implement the url into a type=submit button. This is how i have hidden some urls in my website admin area

Comment: Well clearly they do not if i can change it on a server level Justin

Comment: yes i understand but what i mean is anywhere in the page when someone clicks on a link or a button it takes you a designated area and it appears in the browsers' address no matter what. in this fact what i can say is you require another file onclick which handles the script in the backend and output the results.